# getting json data using jquery ajax on jsp page

Tags: javascript, json, servlets, jquery

How do i get json data using jquery ajax on jsp page.Please can anyone suggest me some function for it.I have to pass data coming from servlet to javascript like var data={"some json data"}

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the jQuery docs for [jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) has examples.

Comment: Can u Suggest one of the examples here

Comment: The link he provided does provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should retrieve from servlet the json string, and read it using a function like [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

```
$.getJSON('ajax/json_data.php', function(data) {
  // do whatever you need with data
});
```

Comment: can i specify url as my servlet file path or as http://localhost:8080/proj/action

Comment: My error console is giving error "$ is not defined" what might me the problem

Comment: You should first check how jquery works, otherwise you will not be able to understand it : http://jquery.com/

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
 //Retrieve the JSON data from the server using AJAX
 $('#AJAXButton').click(function() {
  $.getJSON(
       "/tpm/src/com/gr/view/Five2hRptServlet.java?action=FiveW2HRpt_input.fwh",
       function(data) { alert("data="+data);});
  });
 }); This is the function i am using but its not working i am calling by <input id="AJAXButton" type="button" value="Get JSON With AJAX" /> Where do u think its going wrong?

Comment: Are you using a file path or a url?

Comment: have tried both but not working but the above code is containing file path

Comment: I've already helped you. You need to use urls instead of file paths. Can't do more than that with the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add JQuery into your page: http://jquery.com/

2) Use the getJSON method to call back to the server-side JSP page to retrieve the JSON data: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

3) If you want to parse the JSON data into an object, use Douglas Crockford's JSON library: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js