# ClassNotFoundException: class JSONObject

Tags: json, jquery, servlets

I want a servlet to return json on ajax request. For that I imported org.json.jar. But I am getting ClassNotFoundException for the class 'JSONObject' when I hit the url of the servlet.

I have included the jar in classpath too.

Comment: This will help us, Please show some of your code here.

Comment: I hope this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161846/getting-json-data-using-jquery-ajax-on-jsp-page?rq=1 may help you

Comment: I didn't add the jar into the servlet container's lib directory... on adding now its working fine...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you copy the jar file to your servlet container's lib directory? (like `WEB-INF/lib`)